# How to control 4 workstations in another room?

Tags: kvm

My previous post was deleted due to 'off-topic' but I believe I'm within topic "the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task". I need help engineering my effort. Other than the workstations, no hardware has been purchased since I am having trouble solving my task.

Here's what I need help with: Connect 4 workstations to a KVM (or similar) in Office A, then have a KVM (or similar) in Office B that connects/controls those 4 workstations in Office A.

Office A is simple: Use a KVM to connect 4 workstations to the same Monitor, Keyboard, and Mouse.

The part I can't figure out, and need some help. In Office B is a different monitor, keyboard and mouse sitting on desk connected to a different KVM. I'd like to push the first button on the KVM and see the desktop from the first workstation in Office A (and be able to use the keyboard/mouse). If I hit the second button, then I'll see the second workstation in Office A. 3rd button, 3rd workstation. 4th button, 4th workstation.

No workstation is actually in Office B, they are all in Office A.

Is this special type of KVM, or is there another device that will help achieve my task?

Comment: Re-asking the question is the wrong way to go. I've undeleted your old post; you've got another shot. If you truly believe it's on-topic, then take into account the close reason and comments, and edit your question so that we can see it is.